# How to pass driver details across POM design

Tags: selenium, testng

Please help me in following scenario   1. I have a baseclass and 2.two pages Loginpage and Home page 3.two Test pages, my problem is, from first testpage i have to pass driver details to second test page, but its not happening.    //  package Pom;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Baseclass.Baseclass;
import Pages.Homepage;
import Pages.Loginpage;
public class Loginpom extends Baseclass {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public Loginpage lp;
    public Homepage hp;
    @BeforeTest
    public void getd() {
        driver=getdriver();
    }
    @Test
    public void lpom() throws InterruptedException {
        lp=new Loginpage(driver);
        lp.login();
        hp= lp.transfer();
        }

}
```

//Homepage  package Pom;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import Baseclass.Baseclass;
import Pages.Homepage;
import Pages.Loginpage;
public class Homepom {
public WebDriver driver;
    public Homepage hp;
    public Loginpage lp;
    @Test
    public void hpom() {
        System.out.println(driver);
        hp.home();
    }


}
```

Comment: Can you share the code for getDriver() method and code of your base class, share error if there is any.

Comment: Important note, you must remove @Test annotation in the POM cuz it's not the correct place to use in. And you need to initialize your POM after passing the driver to your class. PageFactory.initElements(driver, POM_Class_Name.class);

Answer (score 0):

you can leverage the use of Singleton Pattern in which there will be no need to pass Objects and only single WebDriver is created and used everywhere . I have written a Snippet for the same, please check if that can be of any help.

```
private BasePage()
{
    s = "I am singleTon Constructor ";
}

public static WebDriver getInstance()
{
    if (driver == null)
        driver = new WebDriver("Chrome");

    return driver;
}


}


class WebDriver 
{
 private String name ;
    public WebDriver(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

}

class LoginPage
{
 WebDriver d ;
    public void OpenLoginPage()
    {
        System.out.println("Opening LoginPage");
    }


    public void showDriverName() {
    System.out.println( d.getName());       
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
         WebDriver d1  =  BasePage.getInstance();
         this.d =d1;
         return d ;
    }

}

class HomePage 
{

    WebDriver d ; 
    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        WebDriver d = new WebDriver("Chrome");
        this.d = d;
        return d;
    }

    public void showDriverName() {

        System.out.println(d.getName());
    }

}


public class BaseClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HomePage p = new HomePage();
        WebDriver d = p.getDriver();
        p.showDriverName();
        LoginPage l = new LoginPage();
        WebDriver d2= l.getDriver();
        l.showDriverName();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass driver details from one class to another class as below :

**Class Loginpom:**

```
@Test
public void lpom() throws InterruptedException {
    lp=new Loginpage(driver);
    lp.login();
    hp= lp.transfer();
}
```

**Class Homepom:**

```
public Homepom(WebDriver driver)
{
    Homepom.driver = driver;
    OR
    this.driver = driver ;
}
```

There should must be driver assigned as Parameterized constructor in the class, for which you are invoking driver. So in your code, Homepom class must be assigned with the parameterized constructor with Driver object.